# Why one controller has repository injected and the other the service

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection, solid-principles

I'm reading M. Seemann book Dependency Injection in .NET, chapter 2. Source code available here: http://www.manning.com/seemann/

In ComplexCommerce solution, CommerceWebPresentationModel, HomeController we have repository passed into constructor:

```
public HomeController(ProductRepository repository, CurrencyProvider currencyProvider)
```

which is then passed to newly created service!

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var currencyCode = this.CurrencyProfileService.GetCurrencyCode();
        var currency = this.currencyProvider.GetCurrency(currencyCode);

        var productService =
            new ProductService(this.repository);
```

However, in BasketController we have a service passed into constructor, to which BasketRepository is injected.

```
    public BasketController(IBasketService basketService,
        CurrencyProvider currencyProvider)
```

As far as I can see ProductService does not implement any interface and that makes HomeController untestable.

My questions is: Why ProductService is instantiated without help of DI? Am I missing something? Or is it something the author missed (in a really good book otherwise!)?

Comment: Keep on reading; I think you'll get there in the end.

Comment: Not every dependency must be injected via constructor, or at all. See page 22.

Comment: @DavidOsborne I agree, but not in this example. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully, [this discussion thread](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?messageID=116799) throws some more light on the matter.

In short, it served as an example, but isn't one of the highlights of the book. I would typically not write code like that on purpose in real production code bases.

However, I disagree that `HomeController` is untestable, because I wrote the entire code base for the book using Test-Driven Development. You can download the code for the book and verify that it's covered by tests. However, I do agree that `HomeController` is more difficult to unit test than it could have been.

For the record, I make mistakes while coding, just like anyone else...

Comment: Thanks for the link that explains a lot. If I knew better, I wouldn't be reading your book! My last two projects were exact copies of your "Doing it wrong" examples. I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something. I agree with you about testing but I just wanted to point out that the dependency makes HomeController tests brittle. Thanks for responding.